# In Odoo11-module, How to create navigation bar action

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-11

I want add icon to open some wizard near red marked icons(refer image) in navigation bar.

[image: screenshot]

Anyone Show me how.

Comment: You can do this thing by add items in `**systry**`.  Here you need to customisation through JS.

Comment: Nice try, please post the answer, if you finished it